# How to retrieve values from multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have an multi-dimensional array

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [lid] => 2
        [docter_id] => 2
        [clinic_id] => 4#1
        [doc_name] => mmmmmmmmmmm kumar
        [clinic_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1250
                [1] => red cross
            )

    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [lid] => 1
        [docter_id] => 1
        [clinic_id] => 2#3
        [doc_name] => vinodooo kumar
        [clinic_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1250
                [1] => red cross
                [2] => chirau
                [3] => nahar nursing home
            )

    )

)
```

I want to print it into the table with the help of `foreach` loop, but it doesn't prints array values.

Comment: what you want to do actually ?? `foreach` works well for your request

Answer (score 0):

What about this? (the HTML is just there for the example).

```
foreach ($arrayname as $i) {
    echo $i->lid.'<br>';
    echo $i->docter_id.'<br>';
    echo $i->clinic_id.'<br>';
    echo $i->doc_name.'<br>';
    foreach ($i->clinic_name as $u) {
        echo $u.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: OP has an `array` not an `object type array`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key==>$val)
{
  if(is_array($val)){ 
      foreach($val as $keynew==>$valnew) {
          echo $val[$keynew];
      }
  }   
  else 
  {
     echo $array[$key];
  }
}
```

Comment: echo $valnew; //in inner loop

Comment: echo $val; //at outer loop

Comment: why you are printing the array by it's key as you are already looping over each value ..?